# ruby match two strings based 4 different criteria

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching

I'm creating a quick search rails app feature. Any help with how to structure the following matching specifications would be appreciated.

Basically, when a user enters a name to search, they should get results based on the following matching criteria.

```
accept match on first 3 chars (e.g. Jon for Jones)
reject match on less than 3 chars (e.g. Jo for Jones)
accept exact match for 2 char author name (e.g. Li for Li)
reject exact match on 1 char author name
reject mismatch on chars beyond 3 (e.g. reject Jonis for Jones)
```

Can this be done with a regular expression?

Comment: The title says four criteria, but you have five. The first one and the fifth one contradict. The second one and the third one also contradict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matchto = 'Jones'.downcase
input = 'Jon'.downcase

matchto.start_with?(input) && 1 < input.length &&
    ( input.length == matchto.length || 2 < input.length )
```